# How to do nokogiri attribute selection?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have many statements like this in my test.xml file

```
<House name="bla"><Room id="bla" name="black" ></Room></House>
```

How do I print all Rooms with `name="black"`. I am using CSS selector but Only `House` and `Room` attributes are taken by the selector.

I started with trying to print all name's, doesn't matter House or Room.

`nodes = doc.css("name")`. But it gives null as the output. So I am not able to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS you have a syntax for matching elements by an attribute key-val pair:

```
nodes = doc.css("[name='black']")
```

For future reference you can also chain attribute selectors

```
nodes = doc.css(".my-class[name='black'][foo='bar']")
```

Or omit the val and match any element where the attribute is present:

```
nodes = doc.css("[name]")
```

Comment: Also how do I get just the attribute value? Currently it gives the entire <Room id="bla" name="black" > when I search for name. I just need value black to be outputed.